# Spring with Apache Beam

Tags: spring, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to use Spring with Apache Beam that will run on Google Cloud Data flow Runner. Dataflow job should be able to use Spring Runtime application context while executing the Pipeline steps. I want to use Spring feature in my Apache Beam pipeline for DI and other stuff. After browsing hours on google, I couldn't find any post or documentation which shows Spring integration in Apache Beam. So, if anyone has tried spring with Apache beam, please let me know.

In main class i have initialised the spring application context but it is not available while execution of pipeline steps. I get null pointer exception for autowired beans. I guess the problem is, at runtime context is not available to worker threads.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    initSpringApplicationContext();

    GcmOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
        .withValidation()
        .as(GcmOptions.class);
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    // pipeline definition
}
```

I want to inject the spring application context to each of the ParDo functions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the ApplicationContext is not available on any worker, as the `main` method is only called when constructing the job and not on any worker machine. Therefore, `initSpringApplicationContext` is never called on any worker.

I've never tried to use Spring within Apache Beam, but I guess moving `initSpringApplicationContext` in a static initializer block will lead to your expected result.

```
public class ApplicationContextHolder {

    private static final ApplicationContext CTX;

    static {
        CTX = initApplicationContext();
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return CTX;
    }
}
```

Please be aware that this alone shouldn't be considered as a best practice of using Spring within Apache Beam since it doesn't integrate well in the lifecycle of Apache Beam. For example, when an error happens during the initialization of the application context, it will appear in the first place where the `ApplicationContextHolder` is used. Therefore, I'd recommend to extract `initApplicationContext` out of the static initializer block and call it explicitly with regards to Apache Beam's Lifecycle. The [setup](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.Setup.html) phase would be a good place for this.

Comment: I used setup to init Application context which is creating `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
        AppConfig.class);` but however i am facing problem for scanning my components. My appConfig class

Comment: When you provide more information what the problem is, we might be able to help you.
Did you also check if all the required components are available on worker, i.e. on it's classpath?

Comment: i have annotated few of the classes with @Component annotation and i have defined few beans in my appConfig. Out of these only beans defined in my appConfig are accessible not the annotated beans.  here is my appConfig structure. It seems componentscan is not triggered when creating new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext object.  Do you what can be the problem. 
`@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.abc")
public class AppConfig {
  // Bean definitions with @Bean annotation.
}`

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` doesn't exclude component scan or so. Does it work locally? For example when you construct the ApplicationContext within a main method. If it also doesn't work in this case, the problem is your Spring configuration and not related to Apache Beam.

Comment: Yes, It does work locally. I wrote the test main method to test this and it works perfectly fine. I can see the bean printed with @Component annotation.  ' public class SpringTestMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {    
    ApplicationContext applicationContext =  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
        AppConfig.class);
    System.out.println(applicationContext.containsBean("googleRecordParser"));
    for (String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
      System.out.println(beanName);
    }    
  }
} '

Comment: Hi @Jitendra were you able to resolve it? I am also facing the same issue but I am not able to access spring managed beans in apache beam DoFn